# multiple apache connections using telnet

Tags: apache-2.2, telnet

I want to have multiple simultaneous HTTP connections to my webserver which has a website hosted to perform load testing.

Can anyone tell me how can we use a 'telnet' command in a script to do the same ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are much better off using [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

Some nice examples

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of very good HTTP load testers out there. It seems that homebrewing one from the ground up would be a waste of time unless you have some *very* specific use cases you wanted to test.

Check out [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) for starters.